# Transition an element when another one disappears

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    visible: true
  }
})
```

```css
.a, .b {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.b {
  background: blue;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.4/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="a" v-if="visible" @click="visible = false"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

How to make the second element (blue) transition to the upper position in an animation rather than instantly?

Answer (score 1):

Hide red div by reducing height with animation.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    visible: true
  },
  methods:{
    hide: function(){
      document.querySelector(".a").style.height = "0px";
      console.log(document.querySelector(".a").style.width);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.a, .b {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.a{
  background: red;
  transition: 1s;
}

.b {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.4/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="a" v-if="visible" @click="hide"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```